# How to display the nearest latitude and longitude to my location using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new in stack overflow and I was wondering if anyone could help me with javascript and getting the nearest latitude and longitude to my current location.

I have an API that stores latitude and longitude coordinates and I have saved those in javascript variables, and also have my current location saved in variables.

I need to somehow sort the list of latitude and longitude coordinates from my list to display the nearest one to my current location.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please give some more details about what you've tried and how your code is organized.  You haven't given enough information to get a specific answer so far.  Generally SO is intended for specific answerable questions, rather than debugging sessions, and so we need a bit more information to be able to give you an answer.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_closestMarker.html) (closest point to the place clicked on the map)? Or [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_closestMarker_geocode.html) (closest point to the geocoded address)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying so fast! Well, I don't want to waste much more of your time so I will be as brief as possible and thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok.. so.. I have pulled latitude and longitude data coordinates from an API and I would like to display them in google maps by nearest to my current location. I have so far added a map with my current location and also display my coordinate database, but it is not listed  based on nearest locate. It is listing random locations regardless of where I currently am. I know I need to create a function that will enable me to get the nearest location to my current one. I just cannot figure out the logic behind it. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Javascript function to calculate distance**

```
$nearest=1; //Limit within 1 KM.

$("#jobnews").html("<h2>Results:</h2>"); 
$.each(info.companies.company, function(index, job)
{ 
    var lat = list.location.lat; 
    var lng = list.location.lng; 
    var nam = current.location.lat; 
    var cou = current.location.lng; 
    //In below line we will get the distance between current and given coordinates.
    var d=distance(nam, cou, lat, lng, "K");
    //Check the d is within 1 KM, If so then add it to map.
    if(nearest>d)
    {
        var map = "</p><img src='maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="; + lat + "," +lng +"&zoom=17&size=400x300&key="+key+"&maptype=roadmap&visual_refresh=true&markers=‌​color:red|"+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=true'width='300' height='280'alt='Map of your location.'/>"; 
        var nearestList = "<div><h3>DISPLAY INFO: "+lis.name+link+nam+lat+lng+cou+map+"</div>"; 
    }
}  

function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
    var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
    var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
    var theta = lon1-lon2
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
    return dist
}
```

**Passed to function:**

lat1, lon1 = Latitude and Longitude of point 1 (in decimal degrees)
lat2, lon2 = Latitude and Longitude of point 2 (in decimal degrees)
unit = the unit you desire for results
where: 'M' is statute miles
'K' is kilometers (default)
'N' is nautical miles

Comment: Call your  the function with your current location and nearest location coordinates, consider the smallest distance return by function?

Comment: I am going to repost my reply. I apologize.

Comment: Hello, This is my code:

$("#jobnews").html("<h2>Results:</h2>");
$.each(info.companies.company, function(index, job){

var lat = list.location.lat;
var lng = list.location.lng;
var nam = current.location.lat;
var cou = current.location.lng;


var map = "</p><img src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," +lng +"&zoom=17&size=400x300&key="+key+"&maptype=roadmap&visual_refresh=true&markers=color:red|"+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=true'width='300' height='280'alt='Map of your location.'/>";

var nearestList = "<div><h3>DISPLAY INFO: "+lis.name+link+nam+lat+lng+cou+map+"</div>";

Comment: It looks very messy but I am not allowed to go pass the text limit in stackoverflow. I would like to know if your code can be run with my code here. Thank you very much!

Comment: Edit your question including this code, so that is more easy to answer your question!

Comment: Hello, Thanks for all your help. I am trying to find some time to complete this and other school projects. I want to thank you for taking your time to help me. I will update this ASAP

Comment: Hi, is radlon1 and radlon2 supposed to be excluded from any calculation? They are just leftovers? Or is they supposed to be included? To me it seems the distance calculation is excluding longitude!?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to include the [Geolib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib) library.

The [first example](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib#examples) demonstrates the `getDistance` function. If you combine this with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) you can get what you want in a couple of lines:

```
var current = {lat: 10, lng: 20}
var coords = [{lat: 5, lng: 5}, {lat: 10.2, lng: 19.6}, {lat: 60, lng: 10}];

var distFromCurrent = function(coord) {
    return {coord: coord, dist: geolib.getDistance(current, coord)};
}

var closest = coords.map(distFromCurrent).sort(function(a,b)  { return a.dist - b.dist })[0];

console.log("Closest: " + closest.coord.lat + ", " + closest.coord.lng);
```